# generic Swipe gesture using html css for charts

Tags: html, css, charts, swipe

I have created some charts and I would like to add swipe gesture like whenever user swipes, the charts have to be changed. I created the charts inside div. I just want to add those div instead of image. I searched but i got to it for images only that too not well documented.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Not possible with pure css try Jquery UI draggable or hammer.js or any other js plugins

Answer (score 0):

For this problem I'd recommend using somethging like Flexislider to implement your graphs:

http://www.woothemes.com/flexslider/